# How to select group of codes and represent a specific weight in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**We have product codes like so:**

```
0001101 -- 1kg
0001396 -- 6 x 1kg
0001400 -- 10 x 1kg

xxxxyyy = x represents the product code and y represents the weight code.
```

I am aiming to group them together as an individual pack size.

**So I had help to get this current query:**

```
DECLARE @date Date;
SET @date = '2020-11-26';

SELECT p.code AS ProductCode, 
        p.description AS ProductDescription,
        SUM(requiredQty * v.factor) as RequiredQty,
        p.weight
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
        SalesOrder so
        ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIN
        Product p 
        ON sol.productID = p.id CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES (CASE WHEN p.code LIKE '%101' THEN 1
                    WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN 6     -- Because it is  6 x 1kg
                    WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN 10     -- Because it is  10 x 1kg
                END)
        ) v(factor)
WHERE so.dueDate = @date AND
        v.factor IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.code, p.description, p.weight order by p.code;
```

This is the current output:

[image]

The codes ending with `396` and `400` `RequiredQty` column now represents individual pack sizes.

As an example, the code `0004400` was originally `10 x 1kg` and had `requiredQty` of `1`. Now it is `10` because in the query I have changed it to represent individual pack sizes. This means there is `10` packs of `1kg`.

**Desired output**

[image]

I need to add the same product codes together. How would I do that?

Comment: I'll suggest `substring` and split the `productcode` code into two column instead of using `like` cause if data show like `0001011` then everything will went wrong.

Comment: @T.Peter good idea!

Comment: and when you got two column one as `productcode` and one as `weightcode` everything can be solve easily :D

Comment: Ideally, you you should make those columns separate in your table, then things are far easier; storing 2 pieces of information in a single value breaks some of the basic principles of Normal Form. If you then "must" have that column in the table as well, make the column a (`PERSISTED`) computed column so you have all three.

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately it is the data I need to work with, it's currently set up like this and I have no authority to make amendments. I totally agree with the principle of Normal Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the aggregation:

```
SELECT LEFT(p.code, 4) AS ProductCode, p.description AS ProductDescription,
       SUM(requiredQty * v.factor) as RequiredQty,
       '1 kg' as weight
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
        SalesOrder so
        ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIN
        Product p 
        ON sol.productID = p.id CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES (CASE WHEN p.code LIKE '%101' THEN 1
                    WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN 6     -- Because it is  6 x 1kg
                    WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN 10     -- Because it is  10 x 1kg
                END)
        ) v(factor)
WHERE so.dueDate = @date AND
      v.factor IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(p.code, 4), p.description
ORDER BY LEFT(p.code, 4);
```

Comment: How can it show the weight? I forgot I have left `'1 kg' as weight`? Other than that, it's what I am after. To access the weight it'll be `p.weight`